# Averaging Grades using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a homework assignment that I have been coding away at. I thought I had it done but whenever I want to display the average it shows a list of 0's in the content pane.

Here is the description of the assignment.

> Write a Swing program that declares an empty array of grades with a
>   maximum length of 50. Implement a JOptionPane input box within a while
>   loop to allow the user to enter grades. When the user enters the
>   sentinel value of -1, that will signal the end of the data input loop.
>
> After the grades are entered, a content pane should display the grades
>   sorted from lowest to highest. Write a loop that goes through the
>   array looking for elements that are greater than zero (0). Keep a
>   running count of those items, and also accumulate them into a grand
>   total. Divide the grand total by the number of grades entered to find
>   an average, and display the average at the end of the sorted list of
>   grades. Use the DecimalFormat method to display the average to 2
>   decimal places.

```
/*
    Chapter 7:      Average of grades
    Programmer:     
    Date:           
    Filename:       Averages.java
    Purpose:        To use the Java Swing interface to calculate the average of up to 50 grades.
                    Average is calculated once -1 is entered as a value. The grades are then sorted
                    from lowest to highest and displayed in a content pane which also displayes the average.
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Averages extends JFrame
{
    //construct conponents
    static JLabel title = new JLabel("Average of Grades");
    static JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    static int numberOfGrades = 0;
    static int total = 0;
    static DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat ("##0.00");

    //set array
    static int[] grades = new int[50];

    //create content pane
    public Container createContentPane()
    {
        //create JTextPane and center panel
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        northPanel.add(title);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        textPane = addTextToPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,200));
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

        //create Container and set attributes
        Container c = getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
            c.add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            c.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return c;
    }

    //method to add new text to JTextPane
    public static JTextPane addTextToPane()
    {
        Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
        try
        {
            // clear previous text
            doc.remove(0,doc.getLength());

            //insert title
            doc.insertString(0,"Grades\n",textPane.getStyle("large"));

            //insert grades and calculate average
            for(int j=0; j<grades.length; j++)
            {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), grades[j] + "\n", textPane.getStyle("large"));
            }
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ble)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't insert text");
        }

        return textPane;
    }

    //method to sort array
    public void grades(int grdArray[])
    {
        //sort int array
        for (int pass = 1; pass<grdArray.length; pass++)
        {
            for (int element = 0; element<grdArray.length -1; element++)
            {
                swap(grades, element, element + 1);

            }
        }
            addTextToPane();

    }


    //method to swap elements of array
    public void swap(int swapArray[], int first, int second)
    {
        int hold;
        hold = swapArray[first];
        swapArray[first] = swapArray[second];
        swapArray[second] = hold;
    }

    //execute method at run time
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        Averages f = new Averages();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        //accept first grade
        int integerInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a grade (0-100) or -1 to calculate the average"));

        //while loop accepts more grades, keeps count, and calulates the total
        int count = 0;
        int[] grades = new int[50];
        int num = 0;
        while (count<50 && num!= -1)
        {
            num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a grade (0-100) or -1 to calculate the average" + (count+1)));
            if(num!=-1)
                grades[count] = num;
            count++;

        }

        //create content pane
        f.setContentPane(f.createContentPane());
        f.setSize(600,375);
        f.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: My advice?  Get the average working before you do Swing.  Once you've got it, you can put it aside and get the UI working.  It's called 'decomposition'.

Comment: The problem is I'm not really good at java so I just went with what I thought would work based on what I learned in previous classes.

I tried looking around online but it seems like everyone else is using an enter button instead which is not what my teacher asked for.

Comment: Dude, we can see that.  Can you write a Statistics class that takes in an array of values and calculates an average for you?  Start with that.  It's especially important when you're not good at Java, because the more code you write the more overwhelmed you get.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the problem, please.

Start with the statistics:

```
/**
 * Statistics
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626262/averaging-grades-using-java-swing?noredirect=1#comment22167503_15626262
 * @since 3/25/13 7:50 PM
 */
public class Statistics {
    public static double getAverage(int numValues, int [] values) {
        double average = 0.0;
        if ((values != null) && (numValues > 0) && (values.length >= numValues)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i) {
                average += values[i];
            }
            average /= numValues;
        }
        return average;
    }
}
```

Next I'd recommend that you leave Swing out of it altogether for a little while.  Do a text-only input/output UI.

```
import java.util.Scanner;



/**
 * StatisticsDriver
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626262/averaging-grades-using-java-swing?noredirect=1#comment22167503_15626262
 * @since 3/25/13 7:50 PM
 */
public class StatisticsDriver {
    public static final int MAX_VALUES = 50;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [] values = new int[MAX_VALUES];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean getAnotherValue;
        int numValues = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("next value: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input != null) {
                values[numValues++] = Integer.valueOf(input.trim());
            }
            System.out.print("another? [y/n]: ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            getAnotherValue = "y".equalsIgnoreCase(input);
        } while (getAnotherValue);
        System.out.println(Statistics.getAverage(numValues, values));
    }
}
```

Now that you have those, turn your attention to Swing.

Too many young programmers get themselves wound around the axle on Swing before they solve the problem.  Don't make that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the `grades` array declared twice. Once locally within `main()`, and the second globally. When you ask for the user to input their grades, you assign the various positions to the array within `main()`. However, when you get the information in your `addTextToPane()`, you call on the globally declared `grades` array.

Once you delete the following in the `main()`, the problem is resolved.

`int[] grades = new int[50];`

Comment: Thank you for that. Now I just need to figure out why it still keeps a bunch of zeros and why it doesn't show the total and average it.

Answer (score 0):

Well , The first mistake than I can see is this :

You are hidden the static array grades in main

int[] grades = new int[50];